# How to put logo in center using css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Before i start, I would like to apologize for my bad English.

I want to put website logo in center using css after Media Query (max-width: 1100px)

there is my css & html

```css
.logo { 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  padding:22.5px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/27060/images/example.png" alt="example" class="logo"/>
</div>
```

please help me :( :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because my previous answer was based on a site that is no longer available, my updated code is the following:

```css
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .logo img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/27060/images/example.png" alt="example" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help you, just set img to act as a character (inline-block) and align center.

```css
.logo { 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.logo img {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/27060/images/example.png" alt="example" class="logo"/>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

with witdth 100% it will never be centered, width must be 50%

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work as your demand.

`@media(max-width: 1100px){
    .logo
    {
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        padding:22.5px 0 0 10px;
    }
    .logo img
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

text-align:center
will work just fine if that's the only element that you want to center/text that you want to center. other oprions will be to add to the  element 
.
btw if you want if also responsive you may give it width:100%; height:auto;

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is based on flexbox. I've put it into a Codepen as well, so you can play with the screen size and see how the collapse happens when the screen exceeds the 1100px screen size.

[View Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/jOPpqjE)

```css
.logo img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/27060/images/example.png" alt="example" class="logo"/>
</div>
```